# List-comprehension output not what I assumed

Tags: haskell

I assume its simple as its in a past paper of my university but the function is:

```
[(x,y) | x <- [0..2], y<-[0,x])
```

and the output

```
  [(0,0),(0,0),(1,0), (1,1), (2,0), (2,2)]
```

The (2,0) confuses me, if y maps to 0 to x whilst x is equal to 1 = (1,1) wouldnt it be

```
[(0,0),(0,0),(1,0), (1,1), **(2,1)**, (2,2)]
```

or is it because due to the y using all its numbers in its list [0,1] it reverts back to 0?

Comment: Did you mean `y<-[0..x]` rather than `y<-[0,x]`?

Comment: @MathematicalOrchid nice shout, thank you!

Comment: err ... now your input does neither compile nor correspond to the output ... may I ask what the *question* is?

Comment: After the edit the question is impossible to understand, since the output is now wrong! You should not correct the error after you ask, if that was the whole issue. Think of who will read the question afterwards, and of who has already replied.

Comment: can you please at least edit the output that *baffles* you? ... look if you just copy&paste it into GHCi (removing the `)` vs `]` mistake) you get: `[(0,0),(1,0),(1,1),(2,0),(2,1),(2,2)]` from this new line

Comment: this question only makes sense as originally asked. Any new question should be asked anew, as a separate entry. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### case `[(x,y) | x <- [0..2], y<-[0,x]]`

`[0,x]`  is:

- `[0,0]` for `x=0`
- `[0,1]` for `x=1`
- `[0,2]` for `x=2`

so if you pair each of those `y`s up with the corresponding `x` you get:

```
   [(0,0),(0,0)] -- x = 0
++ [(1,0),(1,1)] -- x = 1
++ [(2,0),(2,2)] -- x = 2
```

which yields your given output

---

note: `[0,2]` has length 2 and is quite different from `[0..2]` which has length 3 and contains `1`

---

### case `[(x,y) | x <- [0..2], y<-[0..x]]`

it's not that different - `[0..x]`  is:

- `[0]`     for `x=0`
- `[0,1]`   for `x=1`
- `[0,1,2]` for `x=2`

and if you pair each of those `y`s up with the corresponding `x` you get

```
   [(0,0))]            -- x = 0
++ [(1,0),(1,1)]       -- x = 1
++ [(2,0),(2,1),(2,2)] -- x = 2
```

which then would give you the result

```
[(0,0),(1,0),(1,1),(2,0),(2,1),(2,2)]
```

Comment: I meant [0..x] I didn't realise until Mathematical Orchid Pointed out. My apologies!

Comment: so basically you tell me that both my answer and indeed your question is *void*?

Comment: I'm sorry, I made a mistake. I didn't notice it at first!

Comment: @JaneDoe ... but this new line does not correspond to your given output at all - and of course you don't have to wonder anymore because now the missing *piece* will be in there...

Comment: I rolled the Q back. :)

Comment: @WillNess Thank you!

Comment: This answer is very badly structured. "which of course is simply no - the output is consistent" ????

Comment: @immibis you are of course free to add your own - but thanks for giving a reason - and maybe it would help you if you would indeed read the rest of the answer

Comment: @Carsten If you proof-read your answer the whole way through, you might see what I mean.

Comment: @immibis ok yes I see what you mean (I honestly don't know how this happened - most guess one paste to much...)